# How many linearly independent subset of $V$ are there having $m$-elements?

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a field of $p$ elements.Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F$. Prove the following $:$
>
> $(a)$ $V$ has $p^n$ elements.
>
> $(b)$ $V$ has $p^n - 1$ linearly independent singleton sets.
>
> $(c)$ The number of linearly independent subsets of $V$ consisting of $m$ elements,$(1 \leq m \leq n)$ is
>
> $$ \frac {1} {m!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-1} (p^n - p^k).$$
>
> Hint $:$ Induction.

$(a)$ follows from the fact that  $V \simeq \mathbb F^n$ and $\mathbb F$ has $p$-many elements. Also $(b)$ follows immediately from $(a)$. Now to show $(c)$ we use induction on the number of elements in a linearly independent subset of $V$. Clearly our result holds for $n=1$ by part $(b)$. Let our result be true for any linearly independent subset of $m-1$ elements i.e. number of linearly independent  subsets of $V$ consisting of $m-1$ elements is

$$ \frac {1} {(m-1)!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-2} (p^n - p^k).$$

We have to prove that our result is true for $m$. Now we can make a linearly independent subset consisting of $m$ elements from a linearly independent subset  consisting of  $m-1$ elements by adjoining an element of $V$ which is not in the span of these $m-1$ elements. Now the number of elements in the span of $m-1$ elements is $p^{m-1}$. So the adjoining elements should then be chosen from the remaining  $p^n -  p^{m-1}$ elements and this is true for each of these  $\frac {1} {(m-1)!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-2} (p^n - p^k)$ possibilities. So the total  number of linearly independent subsets is thus  $$ \frac {1} {(m-1)!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-1} (p^n - p^k).$$ which is not the required answer we are looking for. I am quite unsure about where I have done mistake?

Please help me in this regard. Then it will be very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're counting each set of $m$ elements $m$ different times, since there are $m$ ways to choose $m - 1$ elements to be the set you add an element to. Therefore you need to divide by $m$ to account for this.

Comment: @bitesizebo would you please be more explicit about what you are trying to say in your previous comment?

Comment: I've added a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your counting you state that every LI set of size $m$ is obtained by adjoining an element of $V$ to an LI set of size $m - 1$, which is true. However there isn't a unique way to do this.

If $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ is an LI set then there is $\binom{m}{1} = m$ different ways to partition $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ into a set of size $m - 1$ and a single element. You can add $v_1$ to $\{v_2, \ldots, v_m\}$, or $v_2$ to $\{v_1, v_3, \ldots, v_m\}$, and so on. Hence your method of counting constructs the set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ $m$ different times.

To compensate for this we divide by $m$ at the end, which will give you the right answer.

Comment: Actually out of my $\frac {1} {(m-1)!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-1} (p^n - p^k)$ linearly independent subsets consisting of $m$ elements every such subset occurs $m$ times because every linearly independent subsets of $V$ consisting of  $m$ elements can be obtained from exactly $m$ linearly independent subsets of $V$ consisting of  $(m-1)$ elements. Hence the total number of distinct linearly independent subsets of $V$ consisting of  $m$ elements is  $\frac {1} {m!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-1} (p^n - p^k)$.